# Stop a time counting function by using another function that is asking for user-input

Tags: c, time

I am not very advanced in c, and I have searched and searched for this topic. Anyways, I was wanting to know how you could write for example two functions.

void counter( int x ){

x being how long to count down

while loop to count up time

When the loop is finished, print out that the countdown is done

}

and then another function to stop the counter upon user input, like if they say yes

void toStop(){

if user inputs Yes, stop the counter and say the time has finished

else, scan for another user input

}

I know there is no main, but I have no absolute idea on how to do this. Thanks for any help that someone can provide!

I understand that my explanation is absolutely pathetic, but here is another explanation

I want it to take an input like ./a.out AmountOfTime  | and then just count down from that time, and if the user types a certain phrase, it will stop the countdown and return it to 0. If that makes any sense. I am horrible at explanations, if you can't tell.

Comment: Instead of commenting a useless comment, why don't you help me?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean it in such a harsh way. It was just completely unnecessary in my opinion. Oh well :P

Answer (score 1):

i didn't understand it properly but what i can guess is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stopper(){
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    return x;
    }

void counter(){
    printf("press 0 for stop\n");
    int i=stopper();
    int count=0;
    while(i){
        count++;
        i=stopper();
    }   
    printf("%d",count);
}

int main(void) {
    counter();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Won't the `while` loop stop at `i=stopper()` ant wait for input?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand what you are getting at, but I am looking for something maybe using the time.h header file. I want it to take an input like ./a.out AmountOfTime  | and then just count down from that time, and if the user types a certain phrase, it will stop the countdown and return it to 0. If that makes any sense. I am horrible at explanations, if you can't tell.